# Flutter Future Builder using wrong request

Tags: http, asynchronous, flutter, dart, future

So, I have two tabs which each load their own data from two distinct response objects. The first tab loads data immediately upon entry. The second tab has a search feature that must be filled out and submitted, which then calls a second corresponding future builder with the appropriate query parameters ( and a completely different url).

Both futures are initialized in initState(). The second future is then updated with the query parameters just before setState() is called (which causes the second future builder to be executed, via a boolean, which tells the app to rebuild).

Everything is working as expected, except the second future builder uses the result of the first future that is not passed to it. The debugger confirms this. There is a quick frame of "exception caught" (due to an unexpected object in the serializer), and then the second futurebuilder is quickly executed again, this time with the right request, and everything resumes well.

I figured that there is some caching mechanism behind the scenes that is causing this, but cannot figure out how to not let the second future builder use the first future builders request. Any help or documentation would be appreciated. I will end up splitting the functionality into two different stateful widgets if I have to, although I suspect the problem will still persist.